# Dynamic textarea is not expanding based on the input value on page load in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea. I am able to dynamically expand the textarea when I type something in textarea.
Its working as expected and I have given max-height to restrict the textarea expand to till 250px.
Its happening when I type something in text area. But in initial page load, when textarea have more
static data, the dynamic expand is not happening based on the initial textarea data.

```
Note- text area min-height should be 100% if there is only a single word ex:- "test", min-height 
should be 250px. 
        
Below is the code snippet I have tried :
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('textarea').on('input', function() {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
#AdditionalComments_div textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AdditionalComments_div">
  <textarea cols="160" rows="5" id="FSLABB_AdditionalComments__c" oninput="this.setAttribute('value',this.value)">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. 
     Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies.

    
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: There was a `)` missing on the document ready and I set a random jQuery version to make it runnable.

Comment: I have made few changes in the question I have asked. min-height should be 100%, if there is a sngle text ex - "test"

Comment: So trigger input

Answer (score 1):

Call trigger to execute the input method.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('textarea').on('input', function() {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
#AdditionalComments_div textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  resize: none;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AdditionalComments_div">
  <textarea cols="160" rows="5" id="FSLABB_AdditionalComments__c" oninput="this.setAttribute('value',this.value)">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. 
     Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel tortor ipsum, vel mattis lorem. Integer interdum posuere iaculis. Mauris fringilla congue egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed rutrum, nibh at lobortis elementum, neque tortor auctor sem, sit amet lacinia odio augue sit amet lacus. Pellentesque facilisis nulla vel dui commodo porttitor. Sed euismod arcu vel tellus faucibus vestibulum. Sed id faucibus enim. Integer lobortis malesuada ultricies </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: the initial page load event is firing but the textarea height is 0 in initial page load. when I am trying to type something its expanding as per the static text given. it is happening because " this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';" retuns 0 in initial page load is there any solution to fix this.

Comment: unclear what your issue is since it appears to be working here.